# Позиции фигур sfml и box2d

Tags: c++, sfml, box2d

Всем привет. У меня возникла такая проблема - тела box2d не совпадают с координатами sfml. Я знаю, что box2d работает с метрами и рисует фигуры относительно центра, в то время как sfml рисует фигуры в пикселях и относительно левого верхнего угла. Но результат разочаровывает.

```
BodyDef.position.Set((object.getAABB().left + (object.getAABB().width/2.f))/30.f,
                     (object.getAABB().top + (object.getAABB().height/2.f))/30.f);
Shape.SetAsBox((object.getAABB().height/2.f)/30.f, (object.getAABB().width/2.f)/30.f);
```

Object - это прямоугольник, который имеет координаты sfml. Первой строкой я получаю его координаты по X и к ним прибавляю его длину делённую на 2. Аналогично с координатой по Y. Таким образом я получаю координаты центра фигуры и делю их на 30, чтоб перевести координаты в пикселях - в метры, чего требует box2d. Далее, в последней строке, я задаю фигуру, которая должна стоять на месте этих координат. Box2d рисует фигуру от её центра, поэтому я высоту и ширину делю на два и перевожу их в метры. В box2d используется система международная система Си (кг, метры, секунды).

Comment: Ваш алгоритм перевода сработает, только если прямоугольник расположен параллельно осям координат. Иначе рассчитанный центр фигуры не совпадет с реальным.

Comment: В этом вопросе отсутствует вопрос. Зачем переводить координаты sfml в координаты box2d - непонятно. Обычно наоборот - мировые координаты переводятся в экранные при отрисовке.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваши ответы!
user7860678, перевожу координаты, потому что изначально позиция даётся в пикселях, соответственно и перевожу в координаты box2d. 
DmitryK, стороны прямоугольника расположены параллельно осям координат.

Comment: *"box2d ... рисует фигуры относительно центра"* Так он же сам ничего не рисует, вроде. Начало координат можно поставить куда хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему! Всё дело в том, что я неправильно понимал AABB. Вот правильный фрагмент кода:

```
BodyDef.position.Set((object.getAABB().left + (object.getAABB().width/2.f) )/30.f,
                     ((object.getAABB().top + (object.getAABB().height/2.f)))/30.f);

Shape.SetAsBox((object.getAABB().width/2.f)/30.f, (object.getAABB().height/2.f)/30.f);
```